# How to use static variables inside functions?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this code to run. How do I access the class's static variable inside a function? Can't believe I can't find a similar question.

```
class myClass:
    proxies = []
    def doIt(self):
        proxies.append(1)

theClass = myClass()
print theClass.proxies
print myClass.proxies
theClass.doIt()
print theClass.proxies
print myClass.proxies
```

Comment: another possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/68645/1281433

Comment: Nope, that doesn't involve functions. I've already read that question twice.

Comment: Did you see [millerdev's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/69067/1281433) there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
class myClass:
    proxies = []
    def doIt(self):
        myClass.proxies.append(1)
```

Comment: Awesome, that works. Is this the proper way and only way of doing it?

Comment: Well, in some cases, `self` keyword can also be used to reference the static member.  However, if you assign `self.proxies` then the object will have both a static and a member variable called `proxies`. It is also possible to have a local variable called `proxies` in the `doIt` function as well.